# Is there anywhere list of all makes/model of all vehicles manufactured for Europe

Tags: csv

Does something like downloadable database/xml/csv file with all vehicles manufactured for the europe market exists, if so, can you give me some links. I have searched google, but didn't found anything that isn't much expensive.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "manufactured" or "designed and marketed by a firm whose headquarters is in Europe"?

I'll bet Ford has manufacturing plants in Europe, but they're an American based company.  And there are Honda and Toyota plants in America, but they're based in Japan.

If you're not happy with what Google provides you, you'll have to pay for it:

http://www.jato.com/USA/Pages/Default.aspx